# Reply back to exactly same client who connected and called with SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, signalr

I am having a two tier application, with one being Windows Form application and other being Web Application with MVC.

Desktop Application has a SignalR Hub area which manages all client connected to it from Web App.

### Hub Class

```
public delegate void ClientConnectionEventHandler(string clientId);
public delegate void ClientNameChangedEventHandler(string clientId, string newName);
public delegate void ClientInitializeEventHandler(string clientId);
public class StockTickerHub:Hub
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public static event ClientConnectionEventHandler ClientConnected;
    public static event ClientConnectionEventHandler ClientDisconnected;
    public static event ClientNameChangedEventHandler ClientNameChanged;
    public static event ClientInitializeEventHandler ClientInitialized;
    
    //Called when a client is connected
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        _users.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, Context.ConnectionId);
        ClientConnected?.Invoke(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        string username;
        _users.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId, out username);
        ClientDisconnected?.Invoke(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
    public void SetUserName(string userName)
    {
        _users[Context.ConnectionId] = userName;
        ClientNameChanged?.Invoke(Context.ConnectionId, userName);
    }
    public void InitializeGrid()
    {
        ClientInitialized?.Invoke(Context.ConnectionId); 
    }
}
```

When web client connects to Desktop App, it's being added and connected.

### Inherited Hub Class

```
public class ClientGateway
{
    private BindingList<ClientItem> _clients = new BindingList<ClientItem>();
    frmMasterTicker frm;
    public ClientGateway()
    {
        //Register to hub events
        StockTickerHub.ClientConnected += StockTickerHub_ClientConnected;
        StockTickerHub.ClientNameChanged += StockTickerHub_ClientNameChanged;
        StockTickerHub.ClientDisconnected += StockTickerHub_ClientDisconnected;
        StockTickerHub.ClientInitialized += StockTickerHub_ClientInitialized;
    }

    private void StockTickerHub_ClientInitialized(string clientId)
    {
        InitializeGrid(clientId);
    }

    private void StockTickerHub_ClientDisconnected(string clientId)
    {
        var client = _clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);
        if (client != null)
        {
            _clients.Remove(client);
        }
    }

    private void StockTickerHub_ClientNameChanged(string clientId, string newName)
    {
        //Update client's name if it's available
        var client = _clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Name = newName;
            SetOperationLogMessage.AddLogMessage(this.ToString(), "", $"Client name changed. Id:{clientId}, Name:{newName}");
            SendTestMessage();
        }
    }

    private void StockTickerHub_ClientConnected(string clientId)
    {
        //Add client to the list
        _clients.Add(new ClientItem() { Id = clientId, Name = clientId });
        SetOperationLogMessage.AddLogMessage("ClientGateway", "StockTickerHub_ClientConnected", $"Client connected:{clientId}");
    }
    public void SendTestMessage()
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.addMessage("Ticker Server", "Hello handshake from server.");
    }
    public void InitializeGrid(string connectionid)
    {
        if (_clients.Count > 0)
        {
            frm = (frmMasterTicker)Helper.GetOpenForm("frmMasterTicker");
            //string msg = "Hello from server at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            string msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(frm.GetInitializeDataFromGrid());
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionid).initializeGrid(msg);
        }
    }
    public void SendTickerData(object lstStock)
    {
        if (_clients.Count > 0)
        {
            //string msg = "Hello from server at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            string msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstStock);
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.Client("").getTickerData(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

### Web Page Code

```
//Connect to SignalR server and get the proxy
function connect() {


    $.connection.hub.url = url;

    simpleHubProxy = $.connection.stockTickerHub;
    if (simpleHubProxy) {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            writeToLog("Connected...");
            simpleHubProxy.server.setUserName("RMSAdmin");
            RequestGridInitialData();
        })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("Can't connect");
            })
            ;
        simpleHubProxy.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
            writeToLog(name + ":" + message);
        }
        simpleHubProxy.client.initializeGrid = function (message) {
            dtSource = JSON.parse(message);
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(dtSource);
        }
        simpleHubProxy.client.getTickerData = function (message) {
            writeToLog(message);
        }
        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
            writeToLog("Server disconnected.");
        });
        $.connection.hub.reconnecting(function () {
            writeToLog("Server reconnecting...");
        });
        $.connection.hub.reconnected(function () {
            writeToLog("Server reconnected...");
        });
        $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
            console.log('SignalR error: ' + error)
        });
    }

}
connect();
```

I can get the connection id from Hub.

Now I have a Windows Form. In which, I want to send data to exactly the same client who connected recently. I have a list of all clients connection with id. But within that, who connected recently and to whom I need to send data from `Form`, I am unable to do the progress with.

Following is a code try inside a Windows Form, which works, but it sends data to all connected client.

```
hubContext.Clients.All.getTickerData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmpStock));
```

**I want to send data only to that client who connects recently. How should I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

In the piece of code where you are sending the windows form data, you can call:

```cs
hubContext.Clients.Caller.getTickerData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmpStock));
```

The `.Caller` will send the message to the client that invoked the method.

You can read more about it, in the oficial microsoft documentation, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients

**Edit:** Since you don't have access to the `.Caller` method outside the hub you need to save the `ClientId` inside the hub and pass it the the outside class... SO there you will be able to call the caller client by id:

```cs
hubContext.Clients.Client(clientId).getTickerData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmpStock));
```

Comment: I am using `IHubContext`, so `.Caller` is not available to me. I can use `.Client` with provided `clientid`.

Comment: @Hemal why? If you are inside the hub, you can use the this.Clients... I believe the IHubContext is used outside the hub.

Comment: Yes, that's my question is. I want to send some information to connected client from a windows form, outside of a hub, so I am using inside a Windows Form this `IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>();hubContext.Clients.All.getTickerData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmpStock));`. Now there is not any `.Caller` available inside `hubContext.Clients`.

Comment: But for sure you are following the pipilene like: user connects => you can store the caller id => call the method outside the hub providing the cliendId => call `hubContext.Clients.Client(clientId).getTickerData(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmpStock));` right?

Comment: How do I get this `clientid` of current calling user inside windows form?

Comment: I believe you can pass it as a parameter when invoking your method for hub to Inherited Hub Class

Comment: I got one finding, that, `Clients.Caller` is only available within `Hub` class. Outside that, where we are getting proxy of that hub, signalr don't know the caller. So we have to get it by client id. So now designing with this idea.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and help. I am planning to send `clientId` from client via javascript everytime request is made. This way I can easily pass that on server wherever it's necessary. Then I will find client with that id and then reply to that only.